# Find location of global variable in elf file

Tags: c++, debugging, elf, dwarf

I want to write a c++ program that can find the location of a global variable.
Here is the relevant readelf

```
...
 <1><98>: Abbrev Number: 7 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <99>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x32): sbox_bit
    <9d>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <9e>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3
    <9f>   DW_AT_type        : <0x81>
    <a3>   DW_AT_external    : 1
    <a3>   DW_AT_location    : 5 byte block: 3 e8 0 1 0     (DW_OP_addr: 100e8)
...
```

I already got the DIE that has the Tag "DW_TAG_variable" with the dwarf_diename "sbox_bit". It shouldn't be too hard to find the location of this variable from here but I can't figure it out.

Comment: See e.g. [use and meaning of DW_AT_location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719266/use-and-meaning-of-dw-at-location)

Comment: A variable may not be at just one location. If the compiler figured out it was a constant it may not even exist. The compiler may also have split it into some combination of multiple variables + a number of inline constants. You can *not*, in general, assume that a C++ level variable is represented as a single named thing in the final machine code. That's way too naive.

Comment: Thank you. In this case, the variable is at the constant address 0x000100e8.
The variable in question is always a pointer to an array of ints.
I think I can figure out the rest myself. I would appreciate it if you could link some examples/tutorials on elfutils/libdw.h. Since that is the library I'm forced to use. I can't find good examples online and I am going by the documentation in the comments [here](https://github.com/kushaldas/elfutils/blob/master/libdw/libdw.h)

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Then you will understand why asking for examples or tutorials is off-topic.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I've never seen a compiler do that, for a non-const global variable. It could do that for constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to write a c++ program that can find the location of a global variable.

You are "holding it wrong".

While it is possible to find the location of a global variable (as well as its type, size, number of elements if it's an array, etc.) from debug info (the `readelf` output you presented), it is *much simpler* to find that address from the symbol table (i.e. output from `nm`).

Parsing the symbol table can be done using [libelf](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf), or just manually (if your host matches the target, it's quite easy to do). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843218/50617).